# Codeigniter How to Group by and having count

Tags: php, codeigniter

Please help, I am have error with codeigniter `group_by` and `having` `count`. This is my code:

```
$this->db->select('*, count(*) as jumlahnya')
                ->from('tb_taruhan')
                ->where($where)
                ->group_by('tebak')
                ->having(count('tebak'))
                ->order_by('jumlahnya','DESC');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query;
```

Comment: What you are trying to do and what error do you get please add relevant details in your  question

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid i need to group by "tebak" coloum  and count tebak column where is have same value

Comment: Still this isn't enough for what i have asked nobody can get complete understanding for what you have stated , it better if you can follow the instructions [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please post your table structure and your expected result.

Comment: You have to put condition in HAVING clause. I think it is not proper. but as you have not shown your db data and what result you want is not clear, I can give only this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The mySql `HAVING` clause requires 2 parameters: a "something" that needs to be evaluated (in your case `'COUNT(tebak)`)  and an evaluation (think of it as a filter)

Try

```
->having('COUNT(tebak)', '0');
```

The above is equivalent to `HAVING COUNT(tebak)=0`

CI allows two different syntaxes:

```
$this->db->having('user_id = 45');  
$this->db->having('user_id',  45);
```

Both produce `HAVING user_id = 45`

Answer (score -1):

```
->having('COUNT(`tebak`)', YOUR_NEED)
```

you called count function, not putting it inside string